# How to make flutter fragment properly fit inside its native activity

Tags: android, flutter, layout

I'm developping an Android native app which is now integrating a Flutter fragment. All works well, except that the height of the flutter widgets is bigger than its parent container.

List views are not scrolling or bottom text is just out of the screen.

```
      child: const Material(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: double.maxFinite,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        ZoneDropDown(),
                        TypeDropDown()
                      ]
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ProductListing(),
                  ),
                  Text("text at the bottom")
                ]
            ),
          )
      )
```

No matter what I tried, the bottom text never shows up, any listviews is not scrolling to its bottom.

Turns out the native activity has a tablayout set to scroll out of sight with:

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

In the FlutterFragment I checked created view size and position, it's a constant 0, so I can't actually resize it to make it fit its container.

I'll try calculating to top of the flutter view, pass it on to flutter so that it can apply a specific gap, but it's cumbersome and will require applying to every flutter fragement.